# Generating XML into xml file from stored procedure?

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

I was wondering if there is a way to place the generated XML inside the stored procedure into a XML file?

Also wondering if this is the best way to do this, seems to be the easiest. If you have some advice on the best way of doing it from a SQL database, I'm all ears.

Code:

```
SELECT * FROM Patient FOR XML PATH('Patient')
```

Comment: I found this interesting article with Google - http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1391-stored-procedure-with-xml-as-input.aspx - http://bit.ly/1aowyJ7

Comment: SQL is just the query language - not a product. So you need to tell us what **concrete database** system (and which version) you're using

Comment: not with standard SQL. However, if you tell which database product it is, there probably is a way.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server.

Version: 11.00.2100